# unix scripting error with sed command

Tags: bash, unix, sed, scripting

I used the below command to replace the "mppu" word with "hihi" and it was working right.

```
sed 's/mppu/'`echo "hihi"`'/' memo.cir
```

but when I was trying the below command

```
sed 's/mppu/'`echo "hi hi"`'/' memo.cir
```

then it gives error as

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command.
```

I really don't why it is giving such error as i just added a space in hihi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct syntax will be as follows.

***Solution 1st:*** For simple replacement of a string.

```
sed 's/old_text/new_text/' Input_file
```

You need not to mention echo and all there.

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you want to search for a string and then do a substitution of any string then following may help you in same.

```
sed '/look_for_string/s/old_text/new_test/' Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** If you want to change multiple/all occurrences of any string into a single line then following may help you too by adding g at last of  command.

```
sed '/look_for_string/s/old_text/new_text/g'  Input_file
```

***Solution 4th:*** In case you want to do the changes into Input_file itself then following may help you in same.

```
sed -i '/look_for_string/s/old_text/new_text/g'  Input_file
```

***EDIT1:*** As per OP, code should replace a variable's value to line then following may help you in same then.

```
VAL="SINGH"
sed 's/tools/'"$VAL"'/'  Input_file
```

***EDIT2:*** Adding an example for OP for substituting the nth number of a string if it matched a string.
Let's say following is my Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
31116441
AAA,hi,hi,hi,hji
AAA
AA
BBB
BB
```

Now to substitute the 3rd occurrence of string(hi) for a line which stars from AAA we could do following then.

```
sed '/AAA/s/hi/cha_cha_ch_ch_cha/3' Input_file
31116441
AAA,hi,hi,cha_cha_ch_ch_cha,hji
AAA
AA
BBB
BB
```

Comment: it was an example but in my code, i will get the replacement text from the other command and that command also gives the same error if the replacement text contains the space.  But the below command works completely fine.                      sed 's/mppu/this is the replacement text/' memo.cir

Comment: you mean from a variable's value you want to replace? could you please confirm the same ?

Comment: not the variable value but it is another command which gives the replacement text for "mppu" but yeah i can store it in variable and use the variable to replace but that is also not working.

Comment: check my EDIT1, where my variable is replacing the string tools in a Input_file, you could put your command's value into variable and then change "tools" with your required string and give it a shot, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: cool, happy to help. You could encourage people by upvote option here and could select a CORRECT answer out of all here(which suits your requirement BEST). Keep learning, keep posting and keep sharing knowledge, cheers.

Comment: one more thing came into my mind suppose I want to search for a line which contains "mppu" in the file and then replace another word in the line which contains "mppu". Can you tell me is there any easier way to do it?

Comment: I think I have given that examples into my answers, see them. eg--> sed '/look_for_string/........ ones.

Comment: what changes would I have to make if I have to replace only the nth occurrence in the solution 2nd command?

Comment: I think /look_for_string/s/old_text/new_text/3 should do the trick, so in this example I am replacing the 3rd occurrence, you could mention as per your need, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Kindly have a look to my EDIT2 now and let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the output from external command. `set -x` helps to debug what is going wrong.

```
$ set -x
# can also use: echo 'asd mppu foo' | sed 's/mppu/'"`echo "hi hi"`"'/'
$ echo 'asd mppu foo' | sed 's/mppu/'"$(echo "hi hi")"'/'
+ echo 'asd mppu foo'
++ echo 'hi hi'
+ sed 's/mppu/hi hi/'
asd hi hi foo
```

You can see that `hi hi` is within outer single quotes. Without double quotes, you'd get

```
$ echo 'asd mppu foo' | sed 's/mppu/'`echo "hi hi"`'/'
+ echo 'asd mppu foo'
++ echo 'hi hi'
+ sed s/mppu/hi hi/
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

Similarly, newlines would cause issue

```
$ echo 'asd mppu foo' | sed 's/mppu/'"$(printf "hi hi\nabc")"'/'
+ echo 'asd mppu foo'
++ printf 'hi hi\nabc'
+ sed 's/mppu/hi hi
abc/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command
```

With variables instead of external command:

```
$ r='hi hi'
$ echo 'asd mppu foo' | sed 's/mppu/'"$r"'/'
+ echo 'asd mppu foo'
+ sed 's/mppu/hi hi/'
asd hi hi foo
$ echo 'asd mppu foo' | sed 's/mppu/'$r'/'
+ sed s/mppu/hi hi/
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
+ echo 'asd mppu foo'
```

See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for more details on this topic

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
sed 's/old/new/g' file
```

if you want to replace variable,you can use the follow tow methods

```
sed -i 's/XXXXX/${WEEK_DAY}/g' ==> sed -i "s/XXXXX/${WEEK_DAY}/g"
sed -i 's/XXXXX/${WEEK_DAY}/g' ==> sed -i 's/XXXXX/'${WEEK_DAY}'/g'
```

Comment: you need to quote the variable substitution, see difference between `WEEK_DAY='hi hi'; echo 'XXXXX' | sed 's/XXXXX/'${WEEK_DAY}'/g'` and `WEEK_DAY='hi hi'; echo 'XXXXX' | sed 's/XXXXX/'"${WEEK_DAY}"'/g'`